# How to join to generate_series with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to bin some events by month.

```
date_list = func.generate_series(start, end, '1 month')

db.session.query(func.count(Event.id)).join(date_list, true()).outerjoin(Event, Event.time==func.date(date_list)).all()
```

But I'm getting an error:

NotSupportedError: (psycopg2.errors.FeatureNotSupported) set-returning functions are not allowed in JOIN conditions

What's a simple example of using a series on the left side of the join with SQLAlchemy, and then using an aggregate like count?

Answer (score 5):

I wonder if you have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53137019/using-function-output-in-sqlalchemy-join-clause) as a reference and forgot to use [`FunctionElement.alias()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.FunctionElement.alias) to produce a selectable out of the `generate_series()` function expression. Now you are passing the set returning function expression as is on the right hand side of the ON clause predicate. Instead use [`column()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.column) to reference the date from the series. Controlling the left hand side of a join is done using [`Query.select_from()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.select_from):

```
from sqlalchemy import func, column

start = ...
end = ...
date_list = func.generate_series(start, end, '1 month').alias('month')
month = column('month')

db.session.query(month, func.count(Event.id)).\
    select_from(date_list).\
    outerjoin(Event, func.date_trunc('month', Event.time) == month).\
    group_by(month)
    all()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked on the latest update of sqlalchemy 1.4 and async

```py
        start = ...
        end = datetime.now()

        date_list = select(
            func.generate_series(
                start, end, timedelta(month=1)
            ).label('month')
        ).subquery()

        response = await db_session.exec(
            select(
                func.count(Event.id),                
                func.date_trunc('day', date_list.c.month)
            )
            .join(
                date_list,
                func.date_trunc('month', Event.time)
                == func.date_trunc('month', date_list.c.month),
            )
            .order_by(date_list.c.month.desc())
            .group_by(date_list.c.month)            
        )
        response = response.all()
```