# How to generate all days between two dates in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

I need a sequence of all days between two dates =, in raw PostgreSQL, I would use generate_series function. How to do this with SQLAlchemy?

Comment: Use `func.generate_series` :)

Comment: Here's one example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53137019/using-function-output-in-sqlalchemy-join-clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it:

```py
result = func.generate_series(min_date, max_date, '1 day')
```